# How to create hash out of specific words in text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, hash

I have a file with the following content:

```
class Rename < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_table :users, :vendors
    rename_table :places, :venues

    #There could be loads of similar lines
  end
end
```

And I need to create hash with the following structure:

```
{ "users" => "vendors",
  "places" => "venues" }
```

How can I achieve this?

I can already fetch needed words using the regular expression with method **scan** `/rename_table.:(\S+),\s:(\S+)/`, but it returns

```
[["users", "vendors"], ["places", "venues"]]
```

Comment: `{ "users" => "vendors", "places" => "venues" }` is a literal, so it makes no sense that you want to create a hash with that structure. It's like saying you want to create a string with the structure `"cat"`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland ok. Maybe I am trying to use a wrong approach for resolving of my problem.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Well, I'll try to explain. I need to fetch a certain pair of values from text files. For example, `"users", "vendors"`. Afterwards, I have to go to another directory and replace files with names `users.rb` to `vendors.rb`. I thought using hash would be appropriate.

Comment: I'd like to help, but I don't know Rails. btw, you should add a Rails tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[["users", "vendors"], ["places", "venues"]].to_h
 => {"users"=>"vendors", "places"=>"venues"}
```

Comment: As your array is a literal,`{"users"=>"vendors", "places"=>"venues"}` would be simpler.

Answer (score 1):

```
Hash[["users", "vendors"], ["places", "venues"]]
 => {"users"=>"vendors", "places"=>"venues"}
```

Comment: As your array is a literal,`{"users"=>"vendors", "places"=>"venues"}` would be simpler.